# Extract multiple JSON strings from multipart HTTP response

Tags: java, json, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm using Apache HttpClient to work with a web service that returns a multipart/form-data response which contains json.

I'm having a very hard time extracting each JSON string separately so I can read the json string.

I did read similar posts on Stackoverflow, and some suggested using Apache commons fileupload, but I am not sure how that can separate the JSON strings from the whole response that has a bunch of other text such as the boundary string, content type, etc

The response looks something like below.

```
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169
Content-Type: application/json
Content-RequestId: GetMailboxes
Status-Code: 200
X-Server-Response-Time: 4ms
X-Server-Chain: domain.com
Content-RequestDuration: 5

{JSON}
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169
Content-Type: application/json
Content-RequestId: GetFolders
Status-Code: 200
X-Server-Response-Time: 8ms
X-Server-Chain: domain.com
Content-RequestDuration: 10

{JSON}
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169
Content-Type: application/json
Content-RequestId: GetAlerts
Status-Code: 200
X-Server-Response-Time: 10ms
X-Server-Chain: domain.com
Content-RequestDuration: 12

{JSON}
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169
Content-Type: application/json
Content-RequestId: GetAccounts
Status-Code: 200
X-Server-Response-Time: 11ms
X-Server-Chain: domain.com
Content-RequestDuration: 12

{JSON}
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169
Content-Type: application/json
Content-RequestId: GetAllSavedSearches
Status-Code: 200
X-Server-Response-Time: 10ms
X-Server-Chain: domain.com
Content-RequestDuration: 12

{JSON}
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169
Content-Type: application/json
Content-RequestId: GetAthenaSegment
Status-Code: 200
X-Server-Response-Time: 14ms
Content-RequestDuration: 21

{JSON}
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169
Content-Type: application/json
Content-RequestId: ListFolderThreads
Status-Code: 200
X-Server-Response-Time: 110ms
Content-RequestDuration: 116

{JSON}
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169
Content-Type: application/json
Content-RequestId: GetUserInfo
Status-Code: 200
X-Server-Response-Time: 197ms
Content-RequestDuration: 204

{JSON}
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169
Content-RequestId: Status
Content-Type: application/json

{JSON}
--Boundary_16003419_2104021487_1483424496169--
```

Any way to do this reliably?

Comment: What your request looks like ? You are requesting `application/json`? Is this the complete starting of the response ? It doesn't looks correct, the `Content-Type` should contain the boundary tag. How do you read the response data with httpclient ?

Comment: @PeterMmm I am requesting "application/json; charset=utf-8" I have edited the question and posted the full response. Thats's how it looks like 100% with the JSON content changed to {JSON}

Comment: The response starts with `--Boundary_16003419...` ? What is this server ? Do you control it ?

Comment: @PeterMmm Unfortunately I don't control it. I have to work with it though :(

Comment: I just ended up using the following regular expression (\\{.*?\\})--  looks to be working fine

Answer (score 2):

One option would be [Apache Mime4j](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/). You would likely want to use `MimeTokenStream` or `MimeStreamParser` as described [here](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/usage.html) if you want your application to handle response content without building a complete DOM tree in memory.